# The usage of "was always"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence, past-tense, present-tense

Good evening everyone! Recentle I've been wondering if it's okey to use always with past simple. Here's a sentence I made up as an example:

*Baking cakes was always a hard task for me.*

Is it grammatically correct?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grammatical. To me it seems less likely than "has always been", because it implies that the possibility of baking cakes is no longer present.

But a case where it would be natural would be if the very thing which is no longer current is finding it hard to bake cakes: if they go on to say that since some experience they now find it easy, then the simple "was" will be quite natural.